# Can anyone tell me the difference between new and :new

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Print_salary_changes
  BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON Emp_tab
  FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.Empno > 0)
DECLARE
    sal_diff number;
BEGIN
    sal_diff  := :new.sal  - :old.sal;
    dbms_output.put('Old salary: ' || :old.sal);
    dbms_output.put('  New salary: ' || :new.sal);
    dbms_output.put_line('  Difference ' || sal_diff);
END;
```

I am unable to understand the difference between new and :new in above query

Answer (score 3):

As detailed in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm):

`NEW` in the `WHEN` clause is used to specify the trigger condition.

> The NEW and OLD keywords, when specified in the WHEN clause, are not
>   considered bind variables, so are not preceded by a colon (:).
>   However, you must precede NEW and OLD with a colon in all references
>   other than the WHEN clause.

`:NEW` is the pseudo-column used to represent the new record in the trigger body.

> When a row-level trigger fires, the PL/SQL runtime system creates and
>   populates the two pseudorecords OLD and NEW. They are called
>   pseudorecords because they have some, but not all, of the properties
>   of records.